# Cannot find web element using WebDriverWait

Tags: appium, appium-android

I **cannot** find a certain web element using WebDriverWait, which returns element not found

```
WebElement e = findElementByCondition(5,new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
   @Override
   public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
   }

});

public WebElement findElementByCondition(int timeOut, ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition)
{
    WebElement el = null;
    try
    {
        el = new WebDriverWait(mUser.mDriver, timeOut)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(ClassCastException.class)
                .ignoring(NullPointerException.class)
                .until(condition);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"TimeoutException()");
    }
    return el;
}
```

But I can find the web element using the driver directly

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
```

Is my code incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I was returning from WebDriverWait based on the first element found, versus using an entire list, e.g.

```
@Override
public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
   Print.tag("apply()");
    List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.className(CLASS_TEXT_VIEW));
    for(WebElement el : els)
    {
       if(el.getText().contains(desiredText))
       {
          Log.d(TAG,"found match");
          return true;
       }
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"no match found");
    return false;
}
```